# Visual Studio solution explorer is not showing class when expanding a form or control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

When expanding a form or control VS 2015.3 solution explorer shows all resource files except the *cs* file associated with it. I can't seem to get to work anyway. I tried uninstalling all the extensions but no resolve.

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this without having to uninstall whole VS?

Comment: It is VS2015, try not the sweat the small bugs.  Just click the "view code" icon in the Solution explorer window toolbar or View > Code in the menu or press F7.